# Inequalities about arctan and tanh.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, inequality

> Prove that for all real numbers $x\geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$ the following inequalities are true:
>   $$\arctan(x+y)\leq\arctan(x)+\arctan(y) \qquad \tanh(x+y)\leq \tanh(x)+\tanh(y)$$

I tried to use both the addition formula and the geometrical approach, but I couldn't find anything leading me to the solution. Any hint/help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $X=\arctan(x), Y=\arctan(y), Z=\arctan(x+y)$. Then, we have, $$x+y=\tan(X)+\tan(Y)=(1+\tan(X)\tan(Y))\tan(X+Y)\geq \tan(X+Y)\\ \implies X+Y\leq\arctan(x+y)~\forall~x,y\geq 0$$

Here, we use the result that $\arctan$ is monotonically increasing on $[0,\infty)$. Can you try the other one now similarly?

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you so much, I'll try it out. I'll be glad to give you a few points if you put this as an answer.

Comment: Typo correction:

$$x+y=\tan(X)+\tan(Y)=(1-\tan(X)\tan(Y))\tan(X+Y)\leq \tan(X+Y)\\ \implies \arctan(x+y)\leq X+Y~\forall~x,y\geq 0$$

Comment: The argument above does not seem correct. Take $x=y=\sqrt{3}$. Then $X=Y=\arctan(\sqrt{3})=\pi/3$ and $\tan(X+Y)=-\sqrt{3}$. So, clearly we can not have 
$$x+y \leq \tan(X+Y)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fixed $y \ge 0$ consider the function
$$
 h(x) = \arctan(x + y) - \arctan(x) - \arctan(y) 
$$
Then $h(0) = 0$ and 
$$
 h'(x) = \frac{1}{1+(x+y)^2} - \frac{1}{1+x^2} \le 0 
$$
for $x \ge 0$.

The same approach can be used to prove the second inequality.

More generally, any [*concave*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) function $f: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$
with $f(0) \ge 0$ is [*subadditive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).